# How do I use SQL to perform a cumulative sum where the increments have an expiration?

Tags: sql

Say the scenario is this:

I have a database of student infractions. When a student is late to class, or misses a homework assignment they get an infraction.

| student_id | infraction_type | day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tardy | 0 |
| 2 | missed_assignment | 0 |
| 1 | tardy | 29 |
| 2 | missed_assignment | 15 |
| 1 | tardy | 99 |
| 2 | missed_assignment | 29 |

The school has three strike system, at each infraction disciplinary action is taken. Call them D0,D1,D2.

**Infractions expire after 30 days.**

I want to be able to perform a query to calculate the total counts of disciplinary actions taken in a given time period.

So the number of disciplinary actions taken in the last 100 days (at day 99) would be

| disciplinary_action | count |
| --- | --- |
| D0 | 3 |
| D1 | 2 |
| D2 | 1 |

A table generated showing the disciplinary actions taken would look like:

| student_id | infraction_type | day | disciplinary_action_gen |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tardy | 0 | D0 |
| 2 | missed_assignment | 0 | D0 |
| 1 | tardy | 29 | D1 |
| 2 | missed_assignment | 15 | D1 |
| 1 | tardy | 99 | D0 |
| 2 | missed_assignment | 29 | D2 |

What SQL query could I use to do such a cumulative sum?

Comment: What is the DBMS? Is the disciplinary action mapping (d3 = 3, etc.) stored in a table or will that be hardcoded in the query?

Comment: It will have to be hardcoded in the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar approach using COUNT() as a [window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) and a [frame definition](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html) -

```
SELECT
    *,
    CONCAT(
        'D',
        LEAST(
            3,
            COUNT(*) OVER (
                PARTITION BY student_id 
                ORDER BY day ASC 
                RANGE BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
            )
        ) - 1
    ) AS disciplinary_action_gen
FROM infractions;
```

The frame definition (`RANGE BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`) tells the server that we want to include all rows with a `day` value between (current row's value of `day` - 30) and (the current row's value of `day`). So, if the current row has a day value of 99, the count will be for all rows in the partition with a day value between `69` and `99`.

To get the disciplinary counts, we can simply wrap this in a normal GROUP BY -

```
SELECT disciplinary_action, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT
        CONCAT(
            'D',
            LEAST(
                3,
                COUNT(*) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY student_id 
                    ORDER BY day ASC 
                    RANGE BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                )
            ) - 1
        ) AS disciplinary_action
    FROM infractions
) t
GROUP BY disciplinary_action;
```

If your infractions are stored with a date, as opposed to the days in your example, this can be easily updated to use a date interval in the frame definition. And, if looking at counts of disciplinary actions in the last 100 days we need to include the previous 30 days, as these could impact the action (D0, D1 or D2) on the first day we are interested in.

```
SELECT disciplinary_action, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT
        `date`,
        CONCAT(
            'D',
            LEAST(
                3,
                COUNT(*) OVER (
                    PARTITION BY student_id 
                    ORDER BY `date` ASC 
                    RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 30 DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
                )
            ) - 1
        ) AS disciplinary_action
    FROM infractions
    WHERE `date` >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 130 DAY
) t
WHERE `date` >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 100 DAY
GROUP BY disciplinary_action;
```

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/PMftBZ6b)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by checking in the following order:

- if <30 days have passed from the last two infractions, assign D2
- if <30 days have passed from last infraction, assign D1
- assign D0 (given its the first infraction)

This will work assuming your DBMS supports the tools used for this solution, namely:

- the `CASE` expression, to conditionally assign infraction values
- the `LAG` window function, to retrieve the previous "*day*" values

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN day - LAG(day,2) OVER(PARTITION BY student_id 
                                       ORDER     BY day       ) < 30 THEN 'D2'
            WHEN day - LAG(day,1) OVER(PARTITION BY student_id 
                                       ORDER     BY day       ) < 30 THEN 'D1'
                                                                     ELSE 'D0'
       END AS disciplinary_action_gen
FROM tab
```

Check a MySQL demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4GYt6EhLvfhcAqFVpjKFSA/0).